# Google Directions to wrong marker

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I have a set of markers, and when clicked on a marker there is a button that gets directions. The problem is that it only gives directions to the last loaded marker from the xml, not to each marker individually. Here is my code, maybe someone can tell what I'm doing wrong. Thank you.

UPDATE: WORKING CODE, QUESTION ANSWERED

```
var map;
var point;
var directionsDisplay; 
var directionsService;
var marker;
var myLatLng; 
var marklat;
var marklong;
var markers;
var DirLat;
var DirLng;

function loadGoogleMap(){
    // load google map
    var script = document.createElement('script');
    script.type = 'text/javascript';
    script.src = 'https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?v=3.exp&sensor=false&' +
        'callback=MyMap';
    document.body.appendChild(script);
}


var map = ''

function MyMap(){

    directionsDisplay = new google.maps.DirectionsRenderer();
    directionsService = new google.maps.DirectionsService();

    var im = //user location icon 
    var CustomMarker = //marker icon location

    if(navigator.geolocation){

        navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(locate, noPos());
    } else { 

    noPos();

    }

    function locate(position){

        myLatLng = new google.maps.LatLng(position.coords.latitude, position.coords.longitude);
        var mapOptions = {
          zoom: 12,
          center: myLatLng,
          mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP,
          zoomControl: false,
          streetViewControl: false,
          mapTypeControl: false,
          panControlOptions: { position: google.maps.ControlPosition.TOP_RIGHT},
          zoomControlOptions: { position: google.maps.ControlPosition.TOP_RIGHT }
        }
        map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map-canvas'),
                                      mapOptions);
        var userMarker = new google.maps.Marker({
            position: myLatLng,
            map: map,
            icon: im
        });
    var infoWindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow;

        downloadUrl("phps/xmltest.php", function(data) {
        var xml = data.responseXML;         
         markers = xml.documentElement.getElementsByTagName("marker");
        for (var i = 0; i < markers.length; i++) {
          var nam = markers[i].getAttribute("name");
          var name = nam.replace('=', '\'');
          var address = markers[i].getAttribute("address");
          var dt1 = markers[i].getAttribute("date1");
          var dt2 = markers[i].getAttribute("date2");
          var dt3 = markers[i].getAttribute("date3");
          var tm1 = markers[i].getAttribute("time1");
          var tm2 = markers[i].getAttribute("time2");
          var tm3 = markers[i].getAttribute("time3");
          var pid = markers[i].getAttribute("PID");
      var DirLat = markers[i].getAttribute("lat");
      var DirLng = markers[i].getAttribute("lng");
      var d = Math.round(Math.random()*1679735965724*236896135089834);
      var raw = pid * d;
      //move up the creation of point
      point = new google.maps.LatLng(
              DirLat,
              DirLng);

      marker = new google.maps.Marker({
        map: map,
        position: point,
        icon: CustomMarker,
        id: raw,
        id2: d

      }); 
      var content = "<button onclick='getDir();'>Get Directions</button>";
      var jshtml = "<button onclick='raw();'>More Info</button>"; //an href function that redirects
      var html = "<b>" + name + "&nbsp;" + content+ '&nbsp;' + jshtml+ "</b> <br/>" + "Date of Yard Sale: " + dt1 + '&nbsp;' + tm1 + '&nbsp;' + dt2 + '&nbsp;' + tm2 + '&nbsp;' + dt3 + '&nbsp;' + tm3;      
      bindInfoWindow(marker, map, infoWindow, html);
        }

       });

    function bindInfoWindow(marker, map, infoWindow, html) {
      google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', function() {
        infoWindow.setContent(html);
        infoWindow.open(map, marker, html);
        center: position;

    document.getElementById('iLat').value = marker.getPosition().lat().toFixed(6);
    document.getElementById('iLng').value = marker.getPosition().lng().toFixed(6);
    document.getElementById('iRaw1').value = marker.id;
    document.getElementById('iRaw2').value = marker.id2;

      });
    }

    function downloadUrl(url, callback) {
      var request = window.ActiveXObject ?
          new ActiveXObject('Microsoft.XMLHTTP') :
          new XMLHttpRequest;

      request.onreadystatechange = function() {
        if (request.readyState == 4) {
          request.onreadystatechange = doNothing;
          callback(request, request.status);
        }
      };


         request.open('GET', url, true);
      request.send();
    }
         function doNothing() {}
    }


    function noPos(error){

        var mapOptions = {
          zoom: 4,
          center: new google.maps.LatLng(41.850033, -87.6500523),
          mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP,
          zoomControl: true,
          streetViewControl: false,
          mapTypeControl: false,
          panControlOptions: { position: google.maps.ControlPosition.TOP_RIGHT},
          zoomControlOptions: { position: google.maps.ControlPosition.TOP_RIGHT }
        }
        var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map-canvas'),
                                      mapOptions);

    var infoWindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow;

      // Change this depending on the name of your PHP file
      downloadUrl("phps/xmltest.php", function(data) {
        var xml = data.responseXML;
         markers = xml.documentElement.getElementsByTagName("marker");
        for (var i = 0; i < markers.length; i++) {
          var nam = markers[i].getAttribute("name");
          var name = nam.replace('=', '\'');
          var address = markers[i].getAttribute("address");
          var dt1 = markers[i].getAttribute("date1");
          var dt2 = markers[i].getAttribute("date2");
          var dt3 = markers[i].getAttribute("date3");
          var tm1 = markers[i].getAttribute("time1");
          var tm2 = markers[i].getAttribute("time2");
          var tm3 = markers[i].getAttribute("time3");
          var pid = markers[i].getAttribute("PID");
          var d = Math.round(Math.random()*1679735965724*236896135089834);
          var raw = pid * d;
          var jshtml = "<button onclick='raw();'>More Info</button>";;
          var html = "<b>" + name + '&nbsp;' + jshtml + "</b>"  + "<br>" + "Date of Yard Sale: " + dt1 + '&nbsp;' + tm1 + '&nbsp;' + dt2 + '&nbsp;' + tm2 + '&nbsp;' + dt3 + '&nbsp;' + tm3;
          point = new google.maps.LatLng(
              parseFloat(markers[i].getAttribute("lat")),
              parseFloat(markers[i].getAttribute("lng")));
          marker = new google.maps.Marker({
            map: map,
            position: point,
            icon: CustomMarker,
            id: raw,
            id2: d
          });

          bindInfoWindow(marker, map, infoWindow, html);
        }
      });

    function bindInfoWindow(marker, map, infoWindow, html) {
      google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', function() {   
        infoWindow.setContent(html);
        infoWindow.open(map, marker, html);
        position = marker.position;
        center: position;

    document.getElementById('iRaw1').value = marker.id;
    document.getElementById('iRaw2').value = marker.id2;

      });
    }

    function downloadUrl(url, callback) {
      var request = window.ActiveXObject ?
          new ActiveXObject('Microsoft.XMLHTTP') :
          new XMLHttpRequest;

      request.onreadystatechange = function() {
        if (request.readyState == 4) {
          request.onreadystatechange = doNothing;
          callback(request, request.status);
        }
      };

         request.open('GET', url, true);
      request.send(null);
    }
         function doNothing() {}

    }

}


 function getDir(){
  directionsDisplay.setMap(map);

  var start = myLatLng;
  //LatLng created based on the passed arguments
  var end = point;
  var request = {
                  origin:start,
                  destination:end,
                  travelMode: google.maps.TravelMode.DRIVING 
                };
  directionsService.route(request, function(result, status) {
    if (status == google.maps.DirectionsStatus.OK) {
      directionsDisplay.setDirections(result);  
    }
  }); 
}
```

Comment: How does your getDir() function know which marker was clicked?  There is only one value of "point" that is left at the value for the last marker.

Comment: I believe that's where I'm running into trouble; I'm not sure how to specify which marker is being clicked. I'd like some help, if possible.

Comment: [one of the examples from Mike Williams' v2 tutorial, translated to v3](http://www.geocodezip.com/v3_MW_example_map4c.html), might help.

Comment: Thank you very much for the suggestion; I've looked at it, and got some great ideas, which have now fixed the issue. I'll answer my own question, unless answer it with your comment and I can upvote you, and give you credit.

Comment: Go ahead and describe what you did, I don't have time to write up a complete answer.  Glad to help.

Answer (score 0):

I globally defined every variable necessary for directions:

```
var map;
var point;
var directionsDisplay; 
var directionsService;
var marker;
var myLatLng; 
var marklat;
var marklong;
var markers;
var DirLat;
var DirLng;
```

created a button for the function, and set in content which is visible in the infowindow:

```
var content = "<button onclick='getDir();'>Get Directions</button>";
```

Next I created hidden input fields in the map page, and assigned values of Latitude and Longitude of the markers that are clicked.

```
document.getElementById('iLat').value = marker.getPosition().lat().toFixed(6);
document.getElementById('iLng').value = marker.getPosition().lng().toFixed(6);
```

The directions function getDir pulls these values for the destination, myLatLng is the current location of the user:

```
function getDir(){
  directionsDisplay.setMap(map);

  var start = myLatLng;
  var LatDir = document.getElementById('iLat').value;
  var LngDir = document.getElementById('iLng').value;
  var end = new google.maps.LatLng(LatDir,LngDir);

  var request = {
                  origin:myLatLng,
                  destination:new google.maps.LatLng(LatDir,LngDir),
                  travelMode: google.maps.TravelMode.DRIVING 
                };
  directionsService.route(request, function(result, status) {
    if (status == google.maps.DirectionsStatus.OK) {
      directionsDisplay.setDirections(result);  
    }
  }); 
}
```

For the full code, see the updated question's code.